# Bootstrap - how to make a single div content not responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm learning how to build web pages based on bootstrap but I'm having some trouble trying to keep two elements side by side on smaller screens. 
In particular, I have 6 elements (A, B, C, D, E, F) and I want to achieve the following result:

Desktop Screen: 
A B 
C D  
E F

Mobile Screen: 
A 
B 
C D  
E 
F

I have no problems with A, B, E and F (I've used the class col-xs-*) but I'm not able to find a way to keep C and D always side by side.

Can you help me? :)

ps my code is similar to this:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-2">a</div>
         <div class="col-xs-2">b</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <div>c</div>
         <div>d</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-2">e</div>
         <div class="col-xs-2">f</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your html in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to specify the column widths at each breakpoint:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">A</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">B</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">C</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">D</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">E</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">F</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To use it in your code, it's like this:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">a</div>
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">b</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-6">c</div>
         <div class="col-xs-6">d</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">e</div>
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">f</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The system with bootstrap is fairly simple.. There for 4 default screen sizes. xs (less than 768 pixels), sm (768px and up), md (992px and up) and lg (1200px and up). You can set up different widths for each size and it will wrap accordingly. You can apply a col- class for each size screen to make it resize to suit. The docs are very good for this. See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Your code should be something like this.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">a</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">b</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">c</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">d</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">e</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">f</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could also put a row class for every two lines.